# when I start test apps from genymotion , I got error

Tags: android, debugging, exception, testing, genymotion

```
(Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while checking library jar)
```

Please can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

This error is generally showed, when you have duplicate dependencies with different versions.
Check your dependencies thoroughly.

you can also use following command:

```
gradle dependencies
```

and if your dependencies are in order try adding following in **build.gradle** file

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: how can I check my dependencies

Comment: Check you build.gradle file in android studio there is dependency section there you can find all the dependency list which is required to build your project.